# PHP PDO : fetchColumn() does not work when row count = 1

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

I have a query that count a number of rows :

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT (D.grouper)  FROM (Select Distinct grouper FROM Operateurs WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$where)." ) D";
```

It work fine when the number of rows is more than one, and return nothing when number of rows = 1 !!

```
$stmt1->execute();
$count = $stmt1->fetchColumn();
```

The data of the `WHEN Clause` is from a form, and i'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Can you use `$stmt1->rowCount();` instead?

Comment: i tried it and give me all the time zero(0) !!